# Function to generate random phone number

Tags: sql, postgresql, random, formatting

I'm wondering how to create a function that generates random phone numbers in the  format:

```
(888) 888-8888
```

Comment: If you want your numbers to be realistic make sure the first three digits are a valid [NPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_North_American_Numbering_Plan_area_codes) and the next three a valid NXX - the rest of the digits can be random.

Answer (score 7):

##### Better with [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE)

```
SELECT to_char(random() * 10000000000, 'FM"("000") "000"-"0000');
```

Much simpler & faster than my original. Multiply the random number with 10^N to get N random digits before the comma. The [`FM` modifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERIC-TABLE) stands for "Fill Mode" and prevents padding with a leading space character. See:

- [Display float column with leading sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66699344/display-float-column-with-leading-sign/66699541#66699541)

This simpler form works, too:

```
SELECT to_char(random() * 10000000000, 'FM(000) 000-0000');
```

Double-quotes are just the safe way to add constant strings to the output pattern (disables possible special meaning).

##### Original answer

```sql
SELECT format('(%s%s%s) %s%s%s-%s%s%s%s'
     , a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8], a[9], a[10])
FROM  (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT trunc(random() * 10)::int
      FROM   generate_series(1, 10)
      ) AS a
   ) sub;
```

Either returns:

```
(213) 633-4337
```

Or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant of code but it's very simple so should give you a basis to work from:

```
SELECT '('
    || (RANDOM() * 9)::INT
    || (RANDOM() * 9)::INT
    || (RANDOM() * 9)::INT
    || ') '
    || (RANDOM() * 9)::INT
    || (RANDOM() * 9)::INT
    || (RANDOM() * 9)::INT
    || '-'
    || (RANDOM() * 9)::INT
    || (RANDOM() * 9)::INT
    || (RANDOM() * 9)::INT
    || (RANDOM() * 9)::INT;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking of this:

```
select replace(replace(replace('(@n1) @n2-@n3),
                               '@n1', lpad((random()*1000)::int::text, 3, '0')
                              ), '@n2', lpad((random()*1000)::int::text, 3, '0')
                      ), lpad((random()*10000)::int::text, 4, '0')
              )
```

That is, use three different random numbers, one for each grouping.

The arithmetic would be slightly different if you don't allow one or more elements to start with a zero.

Comment: I believe the 3rd one should be `random()*10000` (not `1000`).

Answer (score 0):

```
select regexp_replace(CAST (random() AS text),'^0\.(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4}).*$','(\1)\2-\3') AS random;
```

The **random()** function is used to generate a random number between 0 and 1.  It is then **CAST** as **text** and a **regexp_replace** is used to add the formatting characters.

Updated to pad the string with some arbitrary numbers:

```
select regexp_replace(rpad(CAST (random() AS text),12,CAST(random() AS text)),'^0\.(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4}).*$','(\1)\2-\3') AS random;
```

There is no guarantee this will produce valid phone numbers - for example area codes can't start with zero or one, but if you just need to fill in some numbers quickly, this should do the trick.

Comment: Although not very likely, it is possible for `random()` to generate a number less than 10 digits long, in which case this would fail.

Comment: @jgm - good point - I added a second version which pads the string with another set of random numbers.