# Display float column with leading sign

Tags: postgresql, number-formatting

I am using PHP with PostgreSQL. I have the following query:

```
SELECT ra, de, concat(ra, de) AS com, count(*) OVER() AS total_rows
FROM mdust
LIMIT :pagesize OFFSET :starts
```

The columns `ra` and `de` are floats where `de` can be positive or negative, however, the `de` does not return the `+` associated with the float. It does however return the `-` negative sign. What I want is for the `de` column within `concat(ra, de)` to return back the positive or negative sign.

I was looking at [this](https://database.guide/prepend-a-plus-minus-sign-to-a-number-in-postgresql/) documentation for PostgreSQL which provides `to_char(1, 'S9')` which is exactly what I want but it only works for integers. I was unable to find such a function for floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) works for `float` as well. You just have to define desired output format. The simple pattern `S9` would truncate fractional digits and fail for numbers > 9.

```sql
test=> SELECT to_char(float '0.123'  , 'FMS9999990.099999')
test->      , to_char(float '123'    , 'FMS9999990.099999')
test->      , to_char(float '123.123', 'FMS9999990.099999');
 to_char | to_char | to_char  
---------+---------+----------
 +0.123  | +123.0  | +123.123
(1 row)
```

The added `FM` modifier stands for "fill mode" and suppresses insignificant trailing zeroes (unless forced by a `0` symbol instead of `9`) and padding blanks.

Add as many `9`s before and after the period as you want to allow as many digits.

You can tailor desired output format pretty much any way you want. [Details in the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERIC-TABLE)

Aside: There are more efficient solutions for paging than `LIMIT :pagesize OFFSET :starts`:

- [Optimize query with OFFSET on large table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110504/optimize-query-with-offset-on-large-table/34291099#34291099)